# When is an affine bundle trivial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field, not necessarily algebraically closed, not necessarily of characteristic 0 (actually, the example I have in mind is $k=F_2$).  Let $V,W$ be varieties over $k$, and $W\to V$ a morphism defined over $k$, such that every fiber is isomorphic to an affine space of the same dimension.

What conditions imply that $W$ is actually $V\times A^n$?

Comment: you may enjoy reading http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54502/affine-bundles-over-varieties

Comment: Here's another possibly relevant MO post: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58009/non-locally-trivial-an-bundles